# how add a href inside nuxt-link?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, nuxt.js

I have array of cards like this

```
<nuxt-link :to="{ name: 'portfolio-slug', params: { slug: card.slug } }">
  <a :href="card.link>Go to href</a>
</nuxt-link>
```

click on card with nuxt-link should opening page with details of card

click on a href should open external site

but when i clicking on a-href its open details and ignoring a-href

tried use some tags for nuxt-link but not helped

Comment: put the <a> tag outside your <nuxt-link>.

Comment: `<nuxt-link>` renders to `<a>` and you should never put an `<a>` element inside another `<a>` element.

Comment: You can't make an anchor link inside of an anchor link. Closing.

Comment: but i need external link inside card and click on card should open detail cards

Answer (score 2):

If you click that `<a>` inside an `<a>` (it's just what `<nuxt-link>` generates) you are actually sending the click event to both elements. That it's not good practice (even stopping the propagation with js). just don't nest it

Perhaps absolute position it with css if it has to be on top of the "card".

Try something like:

```
<div class="card">
  <nuxt-link  :to="{ name: 'portfolio-slug', params: { slug: card.slug } }">
    {{ card.content }}
  </nuxt-link>
  <a class="card__cta" :href="card.link>Go to href</a>
</div>
```

and

```
.card {
  position: relative;
}

.card__cta {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 24px; // depending where you need it, maybe you need top property
  right: 24px; // depending where you need it, maybe you need left property
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me at this moment

In Parent component

```
 <template>
  <ul 
    v-if="loadedTertiaryMenu"  
    class="nav justify-content-end"
  >
    <li 
      v-for="item in loadedTertiaryMenu"
      :key="item.id"
      class="nav-item"
    >
      <NavLink
        :attributes="item"
      />
    </li>
  </ul>  
</template>

<script>
import NavLink from '@/components/Navigation/NavLink'

export default {
  name: 'TheNavigationTertiary',
  computed: {
    loadedTertiaryMenu() {
      return this.$store.getters.loadedTertiaryMenu
    }
  },
  components: {
    NavLink
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped lang="scss">

</style>
```

in Child component

```
<template>
  <component
    v-bind="linkProps(attributes.path)"
    :is="NavLink"
    :title="attributes.title"
    :class="[ attributes.cssClasses ]"
    class="nav-link active"
    aria-current="page"
  >
  {{ attributes.label }}
  </component>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'NavLink',
  props: {
    attributes: {
      type: Object,
      required: true
    }
  },
  methods: {
    linkProps (path) {
      if (path.match(/^(http(s)?|ftp):\/\//) || path.target === '_blank') {
        return {
          is: 'a',
          href: path,
          target: '_blank',
          rel: 'noopener'
        }
      }
      return {
        is: 'nuxt-link',
        to: path
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped lang="scss">

</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

---

> It is an extension to @ArlanT answer

---

It adds the `<slot/>` so you can use it externally as follows.

```html
<hyper-link class="anyClass" :url="myCustomUrl" @click.native="">Here lies my html</hyper-link>
```

```js
<template>
  <component
    v-bind="linkProps(url)"
    :is="'hyperLink'"
  >
  <slot/>
  </component>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props:['url'],
    name:'hyperLink',
    methods: {
    linkProps (path) {
      if (path.match(/^(http(s)?|ftp):\/\//) || path.target === '_blank') {
        return {
          is: 'a',
          href: path,
          target: '_blank',
          rel: 'noopener'
        }
      }
      return {
        is: 'nuxt-link',
        to: path
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a :href="card.url" target="_blank">{{ card.title }}</a>
```